# Java JPA - Sync Database and Entity

Tags: java, database, jpa, entity

I'm using JPA for my Enterprise Application, and when I change values of row into my database table the related entity (get it by a `find(-)`) isn't updated with new value.

I think that there is a problem of sync between entity and database or a simple cache, so, how can I solve it?

Comment: Is value changed in the DB? You should elaborate question - give example what are you doing.

Comment: Values was changed manually and directly into database. When I execute find from my JPA class, I get old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit the database row not using the JPA you should invoke [`EntityManager#refresh(-)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) using the entity fetched by `find(-)` as a parameter or invoke [`EntityManager#clear(-)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) and then invoke the `find(-)` again.

Comment: I've tried and works correctly, but there are a method to avoid to call "refresh" for each query?

Comment: Well, there isn't any simple solution. You're updating your database outside of the JPA context, so the JPA doesn't know about the changes made - that's bad. Without caching, you'd hit the database with each request. Here you can find more information about [L1 cache](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching#1st_Level_Cache). You might as well read your JPA provider documentation and see if it doesn't define any property for disabling L1 cache.